# Overriding libstdc++ search path at runtime on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to create a distro-independent .tar.gz archive for my game, Open Hexagon, which was compiled with the latest version of GCC (4.8.1) and uses latest version of `libstdc++`.

Since it already uses a lot of shared libraries, I decided to deploy the game along with the `.so` files it needs, including the correct version of `libstdc++`.

I change the default library search path using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Unfortunately, Linux (differently from Windows), always prioritizes `/usr/lib/`, even if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set.

Is there any way to override the search path for `libstdc++` at runtime? The only solutions I've seen so far involve messing with `rpath` or `runpath` at compile time, and that's something I would like to avoid. Another solution would be static linking, but I've heard it's a bad practice in Linux, and I also use an auto-updater for my game which automatically updates only the newest `.so` libraries.

Comment: Could you please point to the man page says on linux /usr/lib/ is prioritized over LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved by removing `RPATH` at compilation time. Still has issues with different versions of `glibc` on older distros though.

Answer (score 0):

Using "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[my new path]:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" works for me.  It does not put /usr/lib at a higher priority.

Comment: My tests show that `libstdc++` is found in `/usr/lib/` even if a custom path is set in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Perhaps I am doing something wrong? Have you actually succeeded in finding another version of `libstdc++` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` while a version of the library is present in the default folder?

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo Can you post you `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` content?